# Call function when press finish on QWizard

Tags: python-3.x, events, pyqt5

How can I trigger a function after pressing the finish button on a QWizard? I am using PyQT5. Up until now I have only managed to do so when either Cancel or Finish buttons are pressed, however I only need a trigger when the Finish button is pressed

```
class ImportWizard(QtWidgets.QWizard):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(ImportWizard, self).__init__(parent)
    self.addPage(Page1(self))
    self.addPage(Page2(self))
    self.setWindowTitle("Import Wizard")

    # Trigger close event when pressing Finish button
    app.aboutToQuit.connect(self.onFinish)

def onFinish(self):
    print("Wizard closes")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found it. The solution was to swap the `app.aboutToQuit.connect(self.onFinish)`
line with `self.button(QtWidgets.QWizard.FinishButton).clicked.connect(self.onFinish)`